# Is this asymmetric Markov chain on $\mathbb{Z}$ positive recurrent?

Tags: probability

Defined by

1. $P(x,y)=1/q$, if $x\geq 0, y=x+1$
2. $P(y,x)=1/p$, if $x\geq 0, y=x+1$
3. $P(y,x)=1/p$, if $x\leq 0, y=x-1$
4. $P(x,y)=1/q$, if $x\leq 0, y=x-1$,
5. $P(0,0)=1-\frac{2}{q}$

where $p<q$. So the Markov chain is such that a step in a direction away from zero has the lower probability $1/q$. Does the stochastic matrix $P$ (here $1/p+1/q=1$), define a positive recurrent Markov chain?

Added: I want to know if there is another argument to show positive recurrence, without having to know a stationary distribution. Is there a reason that forces a recurrent, not necessarily nearest-neighbour chain as above (that is, with the property "probability of moving towards zero is strictly and uniformly larger than going away, at each step"), to be positive recurrent, without having to compute like this? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

(Not really an answer) The chain is positive recurrent, a stationary distribution is given (up to a constant multiple) as $\pi(0)=1$, $\pi(n)=\pi(-n)=(p/q)^n$.

I want to know if there is another argument to show positive recurrence, without having to know a stationary distribution. Is there a reason that forces a recurrent, not necessarily nearest-neighbour chain as above (that is, with the property "probability of moving towards zero is strictly and uniformly larger than going away, at each step"), to be positive recurrent, without having to compute like this? Any help is much appreciated.